# table.setValueAt(..) not working for JTable

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtable

I have a method that creates a JTable and incorporates a DefaultTableModel.

After instantiating the Jtable, another method gets called to dynamically add rows to the that table using the DefaultTableModel. When I run the application, the rows seem to be added, however when I call setValue, e.g:

```
        table.setValueAt("Running", 2, 6);
```

The console gives me an array out of bounds for the "2" and I know for a fact that there are 15 rows and 15 columns since they show. I called the getRowCount() method on table and it returned 0 which doesn't make any sense, since I can manipulate columns and change the cell colors. The method getInformation() includes:  model.addRow(..);

```
    public void start(final String args[]) throws RemoteException {
        model = new DefaultTableModel(col, 0);
        final JTextField iperfIP = new JTextField(10);
        final JTextField qciIP = new JTextField(10);
        final JTextField dlbw = new JTextField(3);
        final JTextField ulbw = new JTextField(3);
        final JTextField baseport = new JTextField(4);
        final JTextField ontime = new JTextField(3);
        final JTextField offtime = new JTextField(3);
        table = new JTable(model) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
            //********************************************
            protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {
                  return new GroupableTableHeader(columnModel);
              }         
            //*****************************************
        };
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        GetInformation(args); //method that adds rows dynamically
        add(pane);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1400, 300));
        setTitle("Title");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1450, 470);
        setResizable(true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Note:
If there is also any way to access the value in a row of a column, that would solve the problem.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: please show the code that adds the rows and the one that accesses them (and fails)

Comment: Sounds like a threading issue. Make sure all your interactions with the table and its model happen on the EDT

Comment: It is indeed a threading issue, I put a join statement and it worked fine. Thank you all for the help!!